# Perspective-origin firefox

Tags: performance, css, firefox

I'm trying to animate the perspective origin property on a div with a (large) background image. This works well in Chrome but doesn't work smoothly in firefox. (Tested on a macbook pro retina)

I've made up a little test in 
http://jsfiddle.net/gZ8FD/3/

```
.item{
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

#box{
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe a macbook/osx issue, because I see a difference over here.

Comment: Hmm with one element the framerate is still okay, but if I use more the framerate goes down to 3/4FPS...But when I use a solid color as background it works smooth.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you mean the shape not the speed.

Comment: Firefox's 3D transform implementation is pretty slow. It's not you. It's them.